# Display all posts of a post format.

Tags: wordpress

I want to display all posts of a post format (let's say: aside). In WordPress to display all posts of a certain category, just need to use this URL: mysite.com/category/mycategory. Is there a similar way to display all posts of a post format? Or any other way is also fine for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [tax_query parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to get the posts by post_format.  For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-aside' )
        )
    )
);
```

Then you can iterate over the results with [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)() (or use WP_Query() and a standard a Loop):

```
$asides = get_posts( $args );
if ( count($asides) ) {
    foreach ( $asides as $aside ) {
        // do something here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// this will get all 'quote' post format    
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-quote' )
            )
        )
    );
$query = new WP_query($args);
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
// do whatever you want with it
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress creates archive pages for each post format automatically.

Use the [get_post_format_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format_link) method to generate the link to the WordPress archive for each post format (although this method [does not work with the "standard" post format](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-formats-help)).

Answer (score -3):

[See The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

`<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

That code above list all of the post on your wordpress site, so to show all post from a category you need the use the `if ( in_category('CategoryNumberHere ')` function to only fetch post from a category. You must also know the number of the category in your WordPress installation.

Take a look at the linked page above, it has a full tutorial and layout of how to do such things. The code specific to categories is the second section down.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I want. I want to get all posts of a post format, not a category.